# Restart Poco HTTP Server

Tags: c++, poco-libraries, debian-based

I have implemented a HTTP server using the Poco-libraries.
It runs a REST service and everything works fine.

The HTTP server runs as a daemon on a Linux system.

Now I want to implement a functionality into the REST service that restarts the HTTP server daemon itself.

I use `popen` to call a shell command to restart the daemon. The daemon restarts and I can see via `netstat -plten` and `ps -aux` that the server gets a new pid and is listening on port 80. **But it does not handle any incoming HTTP requests**.

If I type the shell command directly into a terminal, the daemon restarts, gets a new pid and handles incoming HTTP requests.

What could be wrong?

EDIT

I have also tried calling the shell command with `system(command);` and `std::thread(std::system,command).detach();` but the result is the same.

Comment: Same result with a port above 1024 ?

Comment: Did you check system logs for anything that would indicate the process invoking popen is running into a permissions issue?

Comment: @Marged Same thing happens, if I switch to port 8080.

Comment: @emsworth I do not find anything in the system logs regarding this process.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

When creating the `Poco::Net::HTTPServer`, I create a `Poco::Net::ServerSocket` to go along with it. I need to close that socket before restarting the daemon.